# How to communicate Loxone-Miniserver with Android App

Tags: android, json, hmacsha1, loxone-miniserver

We are developing an in house home automation app based on the `loxone-miniserver` for a customer using Android. I have collected some information regarding this. i.e
i have to follow some steps given below

1. WE get the key by http request: `http://myMiniserver/dev/sys/getkey`
   `(Done)`
2. we convert key into "HEX" using HEX type in byte increments.
   `(Done)`
3. we convert user:pass into ASCII code. `(Done)`
4. we create hmac-SHA1 algo with above key and message. `(Done)`

i have done above all. now whats next. how can i handshake with the `Loxone-Miniserver` device.
i can paste the code if you need. thanks

Comment: Please refer to the loxone-miniserver documentation.  This is not a question that can be answered here.

Comment: @Simon thanks for response. can you send me the link of Loxone forum ?

Comment: http://www.loxone.com/Pages/forum/default.aspx?g=forum&c=1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I thought I would post a link to both the documentation and a thread on our forum that resulted from the question above.

- [Loxone Documentation on API](http://www.loxone.com/Pages/en/service/DOCUMENTATION/Remote-control/Kommunikationslogik/UebersichtFernsteuerung.aspx)
- [Form Thread about websockets](http://www.loxone.com/Pages/forum/default.aspx?g=posts&t=3089)